# JavaScript event listener for images loading on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way in JavaScript to detect when individual `img`s (including gifs) on a page are loaded, so that I could construct a progress bar for the page assets being fully loaded?

e.g. something like

```
var $imgs = $('img');
var k = 0, n = $imgs.length;
$imgs.onloaded(function(){
    $('#progress-bar inner').width((k++ * 100 / n) + '%');
});
```

Comment: `var $imgs = $('img');
var k = 0,
  n = $imgs.length;
$imgs.each(function() {
  this.onload = function() {
    $('#progress-bar inner').width((k++ * 100 / n) + '%');
  };
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rayon pointed about maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
var $imgs = $('img');
var k = 0, n = $imgs.length;

$imgs.each(function(index){
    $(this).onload(function(){
        console.log("loaded image number:"+index)
        $('#progress-bar inner').width((k++ * 100 / n) + '%');
    });
});
```

Comment: First argument will not be `DOM` element but `index`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { //script })
    .on('error', function() { //script })
```